# Самовольное изменение имени вложения при отправке почты

Tags: c#, smtp

Написанный ниже код получает путь к файлу, прикрепляет его к письму и отправлять получателю.

Беда в том, что при получении имя файла изменяется: к имени файла добавляется путь, т.е. если файл лежит по пути "C:/test/arh/filename.xlsx" то получателю приходит файл "test_arh_filename.xlsx".

Вот сам код метода:

```
public MailSending(string filePath)
    {
        MailAddress from = new MailAddress(fromText, fromAlias);
        MailAddress to = new MailAddress(toText);
        MailMessage m = new MailMessage(fromText, toText, subjectText, bodyText);

        Attachment attach = new Attachment(filePath);
        m.Attachments.Add(attach);

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(smtpHost, smtpPort);
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(login, pass);
        try
        {
            smtp.Send(m);
        }
        catch (SmtpException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобным, и как такое лечится?

Comment: У new Attachment есть и другие перегрузки, которые позволяют указать желаемое имя.

Comment: А разве в почтовом клиенте бывает по-другому?

Comment: а если `Attachment attach = new Attachment(filePath) { Name = "MyFile" };`написать - не работает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть 6 перегрузок конструктора [Attachment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.attachment.attachment(v=vs.110).aspx), вы использовали самый простой вариант:

```
public Attachment(string fileName)
{
  this.Name = AttachmentBase.ShortNameFromFile(fileName);
  this.MimePart.ContentDisposition = new ContentDisposition();
}
```

В этом случае имя файла формируется автоматически, пример вы приводили.

Но ОК, если вас это не устраивает -- вам подходит такой вариант:

```
public Attachment(Stream contentStream, string name)
{
  this.Name = name;
  ...
}
```

Если вы знаете имя файла, то Stream можно получить [например](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8624071/save-and-load-memorystream-to-from-a-file) в .Net выше 4.0 так:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
using (FileStream file = new FileStream("file.bin", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    file.CopyTo(ms);
```